# SQL Server CTE and recursion example misunderstanding

Tags: t-sql, common-table-expression

Could someone help me with `cte` expresion? I have a table:

| old_card | new_card | dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 555 | 2020-01-09 |
| 222 | 223 | 2020-02-10 |
| 333 | 334 | 2020-03-11 |
| 444 | 222 | 2020-04-12 |
| 555 | 666 | 2020-05-12 |
| 666 | 777 | 2020-06-13 |
| 777 | 888 | 2020-07-14 |
| 888 | 0 | 2020-08-15 |
| 999 | 333 | 2020-09-16 |
| 223 | 111 | 2020-10-16 |

I need to get all the changes of `old_card` to a `new_card`, since `old_card` number 111 to a `new_card` number 0. So  I must get 5 records from this table having only a `new_card` = 0 as input parameter

| old_card | new_card | dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 555 | 2020-01-09 |
| 555 | 666 | 2020-05-12 |
| 666 | 777 | 2020-06-13 |
| 777 | 888 | 2020-07-14 |
| 888 | 0 | 2020-08-15 |

I think of to do it using `cte`, but I get all the records from the source table and can't understand why. Here is my cte:

```
;with cte as(
select 
    old_card,
    new_card,
    dt
from 
    cards_transfer 
where
    new_card = 0
union all
select 
    t1.old_card,
    t1.new_card,
    t1.dt 
from 
    cards_transfer t1
    inner join 
        cte on cte.old_card = t1.new_card)
```

But I get 8 rows instead. Can someone tell me please what I did wrong?

Comment: You haven't mention `111` in the Query

Comment: key point here is i don't know about the last raw and that the card number 111 was enrolled to a new chain of transfers which I must not get as the result query. So how can I get only my 5 rows of trnasfer chain having only one input parameter "new_card=0" or is it impossible by using only one cte and I have to do more complex query?

Comment: ;Aside: 'From [Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): "`;` Transact-SQL statement terminator. Although the semicolon is not required for most statements in this version of SQL Server, it will be required in a future version." ;;A semicolon is not a prefix, i.e. ;;;it isn't used to start a statement.

Answer (score 2):

You said you wanted from `111` onwards. So you need to add that "stop" condition

```
where cte.old_card <> 111
```

---

```
;with cte as(
select 
    old_card,
    new_card,
    dt
from 
    cards_transfer 
where
    new_card = 0
union all
select 
    t1.old_card,
    t1.new_card,
    t1.dt 
from 
    cards_transfer t1
    inner join 
        cte on cte.old_card = t1.new_card
where cte.old_card <> 111
)
```

Comment: The problem wasn't in the cte it self as I found out. It was in this particular task. After rereading the task several times I notieced that my 5 rows I should get as the the result is the one chain of card transfers. Whereas the second new_card number 111 in the last row is another chain of transfers. And previous dt can't be larger than the next one in one chain. So I limited it by dt condition and it worked.